# How to show $\zeta_p\in K$

Tags: field-theory, algebraic-number-theory, extension-field, cyclotomic-fields

Let $p$ be a prime and let $K$ be a field of characteristic $d$ co-prime to $p$. Let $a\in K$. I want to show, $a\in (K^*)^p\iff a\in (K(\zeta_p)^*)^p$, and this would eventually imply $\zeta_p\in K$.

If $a\in (K^*)^p$, as $(K^*)^p\subset (K(\zeta_p)^*)^p$, $a\in (K(\zeta_p)^*)^p$. If $a\in (K(\zeta_p)^*)^p$, $a=(a_0+a_1\zeta_p+...)^p$, therefore, taking norms we get $a^k=a_n^p$. Here, $k$ is $[K(\zeta_p):K]$, and $a_n=norm(a_0+a_1\zeta_p+...)$. As, $k$ is coprime to $p$, $kx+py=1$. Therefore, $a^{kx}=a^{1-py}\Rightarrow a=(a_n^xa^{y})^p$. As, $a_n^xa^{y}\in K$, we get that $a\in (K^*)^p$. Now, from this how to show $\zeta_p\in K$. One idea is to show there is another root of $x^p-a$ in $K$, but how to show that?

Comment: Why would $\zeta_p\in K$ ? Perhaps you meant $F(b)/F$ is normal with $b\not \in F, b^p \in F$ (in which case it is immediate that some conjugate of $b$, of the form $\zeta_p^j b$ is in $F(b)$ so $\zeta_p\in F(b)$)

Comment: No I refer to this only.. I posted a problem few days ago..https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3976074/nth-root-of-alpha. I am approaching to solve this from a hint. Actually what I stated above reduces the problem to Kummer theory from which the actual problem (the link that I posted )gets solved, otherwise if $\zeta_p\notin K(\zeta_p)$, then it lies in an extension and the degree of extension is $p$. To understand this, please view the link I have given..

Comment: Your comment doesn't make much sense. Your other question is elementary, with $a^{1/n}$ a root of $x^n-a$ minimizing $[K(a^{1/n}):K]$, it suffices to show that  $p^k|[K(a^{1/p^k}):K]$ which follows from $K(a^{1/p})\cap K(\zeta_p)=K$.

Comment: The question asks to show that $[K(a^{1/n}):K]\mid n$, how can this be done by showing $p^k|[K(a^{1/p^k}):K]$?

Comment: Once $p^k|[K(a^{1/p^k}):K]$ then $[K(a^{1/n}):K]=\prod_{p^k\| n} [K(a^{1/p^k}):K]$ (if $[E:K],[F:K]$ are coprime then $[EF:K]=[E:K][F:K]$)

Comment: Can you please post an answer to that question so that I can understand.. No one has answered that yet .. Thanks